# Remove a table column using code first ASP MVC

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I have two class `A` and `B`. `B` has a foreign key to `A`.

```
class A {
     byte Id{get; set;}
     string Name{get;set;}
 }
```

and

```
class B {
     byte Id{get; set;}
     string Name{get;set;}
     A A{get;set;}
     byte AId{get;set;}
 }
```

My problem is:

1. I created a class `A` with a property `id` of type `int`
2. I run `update-database`
3. I modified data type of `id` to `byte`
4. I run `update-database` again
5. I found that in table `B` that use `id` of `A` as the foreign key has two columns, i.e., `aId` and `a_Id`.

My question is: how can I remove the column `a_Id` using code first approach? Or anyway that is feasible.

I tried to run the query: `ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN a_Id` - **failed because one or more objects access this column.**

I also tried to delete the column directly using VS Server explorer, remove the column by using table definition. But it did not work too.

Thanks

Comment: Should you provide A, B class source code? "text" question will get back text answer

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these steps

1: Remove properties from the model.
2: Run 'Enable-Migrations' in package manage console.
3: Next Run 'Add-Migration "MigrationsName"'. if any case it is showing 'The project  tesproject failed to build then build project again.
4: Now run 'Update-Database'

Comment: What do you mean by remove properties from the model? Remove `A` related properties from `B`, e.g., `id`??

Comment: The property that you are trying to remove from database table

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to change B's FK type in the model.

```
[Required]
public byte ClassAId{ get; set; }

public virtual ClassA ClassA{ get; set; }
```

Also check out what you have in your migration's Up and Down methods.

Attribute [Key] over classA's Id could also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Comment B class and Update-database! (drop table)
again update-database with B class! :) for me this work!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while I was learning ASP.net
the solution to delete the unwanted prop is the following:

1- you have to delete it as an index
so add new migration and write this instruction in the UP method

```
    DropIndex("dbo.TableName", new[] { "ColumnName" });
```

2- update-database
note: at this phase you can make sure that the index has gone if you open the definition of the table (SQL code)

3- New migration but now write in the Up method

```
 DropColumn("TableName", "ColumnName");
```

4- Update-database

and it's gone